# Python3 list remove string is too much time,i need efficient way

Tags: python-3.x, list

**This is my data list**

```
data_list = [
'https://img2.doubanio.com/view/photo/s_ratio_poster/public/p2372307693.jpg', 'https://img2.doubanio.com/view/photo/s_ratio_poster/public/p2616355133.jpg',
 'http://42.194.197.95:8001/poison_img_url', 
'https://img2.doubanio.com/view/photo/s_ratio_poster/public/p480747492.jpg', 'https://img2.doubanio.com/view/photo/s_ratio_poster/public/p2578474613.jpg', 'https://img9.doubanio.com/view/photo/s_ratio_poster/public/p457760035.jpg', 'https://img1.doubanio.com/view/photo/s_ratio_poster/public/p524964039.jpg', 'https://img3.doubanio.com/view/photo/s_ratio_poster/public/p511118051.jpg', 'https://img1.doubanio.com/view/photo/s_ratio_poster/public/p2557573348.jpg', 'https://img3.doubanio.com/view/photo/s_ratio_poster/public/p2561716440.jpg',
 'http://42.194.197.95:8001/poison_img_url', 
'https://img2.doubanio.com/view/photo/s_ratio_poster/public/p492406163.jpg',
 'http://42.194.197.95:8001/poison_img_url'
]
```

**I want to remove string in the list,but,My solution is too time consuming,i need some efficient way**

```
def make_url(data_list,remove_str):
  img_array = []
  #print(result)
  for index,x in enumerate(data_list):
     if(remove_str == x):
         data_list.append(x)
  print(url_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    remove_str = 'http://42.194.197.95:8001/poison_img_url'
    t1 = time.time()
    make_url(data_list,remove_str)
    t2 =time.time()
    print(t2-t1)//7s too slowly
```

Comment: The list comprehension ans. by @VishalSingh is the best way; search & removal from the list will be O(n). If linear complexity is infeasible, you can use `dict` instead.

Comment: `list.remove` is `O(1)` only when the element is the last element, otherwise, it is `O(n)` since all the elements after the removed element need to be shuffled down in memory so the list is still a contiguous block. So a trick if you do not maintain order is to move the element you want to remove to the end first via a swap.

Regardless, it would still be more efficient to create a new list as mentioned in the below answers.

Comment: I runing your code just now ,the running time is 7s ,Can't solve my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use list comprehension to keep items not equal to x

```
def make_url(data_list, remove_str):

    data_list[:] = [x for x in data_list if remove_str != x]  # this will change the original list
```

if you want to return a new list then use return statement inside your function.

```
return [x for x in data_list if remove_str != x]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) method:

```
value_to_be_removed = 'http://42.194.197.95:8001/poison_img_url'
result = list(filter(lambda val: val != value_to_be_removed, url_list))
```

Comment: depending on the size of your data though, you might want to opt for a list comprehension approach. Hopefully this provides some insight though: https://blog.finxter.com/python-lists-filter-vs-list-comprehension-which-is-faster/

Comment: val:val  //what is ? i never use filter in python3.

Comment: The filter() method filters a given sequence with the help of a function that tests each element in the sequence to be true or not. It is commonly used with a lambda function